# Shiny: geom area not showing all groups

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a geom area graph using Shiny. I am able to make the static graph, as shown below, but I am not getting the correct graph output in the actual shiny app.

I have data such as this:

```
dat <- read_table2("term_year_fct   mean    value   Program name    subgroup_fct    Year
Summer&Fall2017 7.647482014 139 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    1
Winter&Spring2018   6.34741784  213 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    2
Summer&Fall2018 7.166666667 246 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    3
Winter&Spring2019   7.759036145 249 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    4
Summer&Fall2019 11.97986577 149 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    5
Summer&Fall2017 8.769230769 104 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   1
Winter&Spring2018   8.563380282 142 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   2
Summer&Fall2018 9.51497006  167 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   3
Winter&Spring2019   9.675824176 182 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   4
Summer&Fall2019 12.44680851 141 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   5
")
```

To use geom area to make a graph, I know I can use this:

```
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y = value,fill = subgroup_fct)) +
  geom_area(aes(colour = subgroup_fct, fill = subgroup_fct), color = "white", position = "identity", stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle(unique(dat$Program))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#285560", "#57a6b9", "#8fa13a")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 300), expand = c(0, 20)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1:5),
                     labels = str_wrap(levels(program_components$term_year_fct),
                                       width = 15)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Count of \nUnique Users\n") +

  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "All Users", value, "")),
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1, show.legend = FALSE)  +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "STEM Users", value, "")),
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "Frequent Users", value, "")),
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  # Specify theme
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  # Remove gray panel background
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "Calibri"),  # Specify text size
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center the title
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center text
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, margin = margin(r = 10)),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),  # Remove ticks
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5, family = "Calibri"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5, family = "Calibri"),# Set labels at 45 degree angle
        legend.title = element_blank(),  # Remove legend title
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

I am trying to create a shiny dashboard for this graph, but the data isn't showing properly when I want to see all the groups at once. For example, this is what I am seeing in my app instead:

[image]

### This is the shiny code I have going. Any idea what I might be missing?

```
dat <- read_table2("term_year_fct   mean    value   Program name    subgroup_fct    Year
Summer&Fall2017 7.647482014 139 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    1
Winter&Spring2018   6.34741784  213 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    2
Summer&Fall2018 7.166666667 246 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    3
Winter&Spring2019   7.759036145 249 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    4
Summer&Fall2019 11.97986577 149 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    5
Summer&Fall2017 8.769230769 104 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   1
Winter&Spring2018   8.563380282 142 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   2
Summer&Fall2018 9.51497006  167 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   3
Winter&Spring2019   9.675824176 182 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   4
Summer&Fall2019 12.44680851 141 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   5
")
dat_in <-dat
# dat_in <- readxl::read_excel("tab2_exampledata_w.xlsx") %>% filter(!is.na(value))



library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel(""),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_prog"),
    
    uiOutput("choose_name"),
    br(),
  ),
  
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Drop down selection to chose the program 
  output$choose_prog <- renderUI({
    selectInput("program", "STEM Program", unique(dat_in$Program))
  })
  
  output$choose_name <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    # if(is.null(input$program))
    #   return()
    
    # Get the program with the appropriate names
    dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program)
    name_options <- unique(dat$name)
    
    # Create the check boxes & select them all by default 
    checkboxGroupInput("names", "select category of interest", 
                       choices = name_options,
                       selected = name_options)
    
  })
  
  # dat <- reactive({
  #   dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name==input$names)
  #   return(dat)
  # })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
  # Output the plot
    
    dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name==input$names)
    
    # head(dat)
    # head(dat)
    dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Year,y = value,fill = subgroup_fct)) + 
      geom_area(aes(colour = subgroup_fct, fill = subgroup_fct), color = "white", position = "identity") +
      ggtitle(unique(dat$Program))+ 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#285560", "#57a6b9", "#8fa13a")) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 300), expand = c(0, 20)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1:5),
                         labels = str_wrap(levels(program_components$term_year_fct),
                                           width = 15)) + 
      xlab("") + 
      ylab("Count of \nUnique Users\n") + 
      
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "All Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1, show.legend = FALSE)  +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "STEM Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "Frequent Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
      # Specify theme
      theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  # Remove gray panel background
            text = element_text(size = 12, family = "Calibri"),  # Specify text size
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center the title
            plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center text
            axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, margin = margin(r = 10)), 
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),  # Remove ticks
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5, family = "Calibri"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5, family = "Calibri"),# Set labels at 45 degree angle
            legend.title = element_blank(),  # Remove legend title
            legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) # Remove gray fill for legend keys
    
    
  })
  
}  
  
  
  
  #
  




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `%in%` in the following line instead of `==`

`dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name == input$names)`

Try this:

`dat <-subset(dat_in, Program %in% input$program & name %in% input$names)`